# Can a warlock activate Eldritch Blast while grappled? If so, are there any penalties?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, warlock, grapple

We have a warlock who is successfully grappled by a vine monster. Can the warlock attack with eldritch blast?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No

Although the warlock's invocations, as well as its eldritch blast, are spell-like abilities, they require somatic components, as spells do (*Complete Arcane* p.7). So, any condition or effect that inhibits casting spells with a somatic component, such as [grappling](http://dndsrd.net/specialAttacks.html#grapple-cast-a-spell), has the same effect on the warlock's invocations, and eldritch blast.

Additionally, though the rules regarding eldritch blast say that the movements are simpler than for casting spells, the only game effect this produces is to allow the warlock to use them in light armor without chance for spell failure.

Comment: Regarding your second paragraph, is there a source for the assertion “the only game effect this produces is to allow the warlock to use them in light armor without chance for spell failure.”?

Comment: My bad, Eldritch Blast is specified to have a somatic component under the Weapon/Armor proficiencies paragraph

Comment: @Saryk No sweat, we figured it out in the end.

Comment: @Luke same page in Complete Arcane.